# the parameters of matplotlib hist() don't work on the server-side

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('agg')
plt.ioff()
fig=plt.figure()
plt.hist(snr,bins=100,range=(0,80),density=True,histtype=u'bar')
plt.savefig('snr.eps',format='eps')
plt.close()
```

`snr` is my data and the code can draw the correct figure on my mac. However, when i unload the program to my workstation, a ubuntu system server, all the parameters of `hist()` are inefficient. Due to some GUI problem of the workstation, I add the `plt.switch_backend('agg')` and `plt.ioff()`. Do they lead to the problem?

The first one is plot on my mac
[image: The first one is plot on my mac]

and the second one is plot on the server-side
[image: and the second one is plot on the server-side]

Both of the version of `matplotlib` are 2.2.2 that seems not the problem.

It's not caused by version difference because I download the wrong figure from a wrong director path at server. I don't know how the second figure be ploted but the figure is right similar to the first one when I download it from the correct director path.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are they using the same version of matplotlib?

Comment: Looks like on your server you are running matplotlib 2.0 while on your mac you run matplotlib 2.1 or higher.

Comment: They have the same version of 2.2.2

Comment: You may find out by putting the version in the title, `plt.title(matplotlib.__version__)`